# Webscraping: I am getting output in the incorrect columns and format. How can I get it the desired format and columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

My code that scrapes [www.oddsportal.com](http://www.oddsportal.com) is scraping data in the incrorrect form.

Code:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

urls = {
    "https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/"
}
class GameData:

    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []
        self.country = []
        self.league = []


def parse_data(url):
    browser.get(url)
    df = pd.read_html(browser.page_source, header=0)[0]
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = bs(html, "lxml")
    cont = soup.find('div', {'id': 'wrap'})
    content = cont.find('div', {'id': 'col-content'})
    content = content.find('table', {'class': 'table-main'}, {'id': 'table-matches'})
    main = content.find('th', {'class': 'first2 tl'})
    if main is None:
        return None
    count = main.findAll('a')
    country = count[0].text
    league = count[1].text
    game_data = GameData()
    game_date = None
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if not isinstance(row[1], str):
            continue
        elif ':' not in row[1]:
            game_date = row[1].split('-')[0]
            continue
        game_data.date.append(game_date)
        game_data.time.append(row[1])
        game_data.game.append(row[2])
        game_data.score.append(row[3])
        game_data.home_odds.append(row[4])
        game_data.draw_odds.append(row[5])
        game_data.away_odds.append(row[6])
        game_data.country.append(country)
        game_data.league.append(league)
    return game_data
```

df:

```
|     | date                                  | time   | game                                             | score                                            | home_odds   | draw_odds   | away_odds   | country   | league               |
|-----|---------------------------------------|--------|--------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-----------|----------------------|
|   0 |                                       | 00:00  | Tomayapo - Independiente Petroleros              | Tomayapo - Independiente Petroleros              | 1.82        | 3.70        | 3.59        | Bolivia   | Division Profesional |
|   1 | Ecuador»Liga Pro                      | 00:00  | Dep. Cuenca - Mushuc Runa                        | Dep. Cuenca - Mushuc Runa                        | 2.34        | 3.18        | 2.93        | Bolivia   | Division Profesional |
|   2 | USA»USL Championship                  | 00:00  | Sporting Kansas City 2 - Colorado Springs        | Sporting Kansas City 2 - Colorado Springs        | 2.18        | 3.48        | 2.95        | Bolivia   | Division Profesional |
|   3 | Brazil»Campeonato Paulista            | 00:30  | Sao Paulo - Ferroviaria                          | Sao Paulo - Ferroviaria                          | 1.51        | 3.93        | 6.15        | Bolivia   | Division Profesional |
|   4 | Venezuela»Primera Division            | 00:30  | Universidad Central - AC Lala FC                 | Universidad Central - AC Lala FC                 | 2.37        | 3.08        | 2.88        | Bolivia   | Division Profesional |
```

This is the incorrect format.

The correct and the desired format is:

```
|     | date        | time   | game                                             |   score | home_odds   | draw_odds   | away_odds   | country                | league                      |
|-----|-------------|--------|--------------------------------------------------|---------|-------------|-------------|-------------|------------------------|-----------------------------|
|   0 | 15 May 2021 | 0:00   | Tomayapo - Independiente Petroleros              |     nan | 1.82        | 3.7         | 3.59        | Bolivia                | Division Profesional        |
|   1 | 15 May 2021 | 0:00   | Dep. Cuenca - Mushuc Runa                        |     nan | 2.34        | 3.18        | 2.93        | Ecuador                | Liga Pro                    |
|   2 | 15 May 2021 | 0:00   | Sporting Kansas City 2 - Colorado Springs        |     nan | 2.18        | 3.48        | 2.95        | USA                    | USL Championship            |
|   3 | 15 May 2021 | 0:30   | Sao Paulo - Ferroviaria                          |     nan | 1.51        | 3.93        | 6.15        | Brazil                 | Campeonato Paulista         |
|   4 | 15 May 2021 | 0:30   | Universidad Central - AC Lala FC                 |     nan | 2.37        | 3.08        | 2.88        | Venezuela              | Primera Division            |
```

How can I frame my code correctly to get the desired format.

If it helps, the `Xpath` for the part I am trying to scrape is:

//*[@id="table-matches"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a[2]

Help is greatly apreciated.

Comment: Kudos for avoiding the common misspelling _"webscrapping",_ but you still have to leave one _p._

Comment: More seriously, thanks for providing enough detail; but this is now perhaps _too_ detailed. Try to reduce the problem to a [mre].

Comment: @tripleee So sorry for the typo. This is so embarassing. I have corrected the title and the body for a minimum reproducible example. I had questions to add full code before hence the extra bit. I have taken that part out. I guess I am not building the df correctly hence the nature of the output. Thanks very much.